# Trying to prepend a Hashtag symbol to the_tags links

Tags: php, jquery, links, tags

I want to prepend a hashtag (#) in front of the tags on my post pages in Wordpress using jQuery. This code is not working:

```
$('div.tags a').prepend('#');
```

This is the php:

```
<div class="tags">
    <?php the_tags( ' ', ' ', '' ); ?>
</div>
```

I don't want the "#" to be part of the the stored tag, just added for display purposes. Thank you.

Comment: Vote to close as off topic as you need a generic js/css solution and not a WordPress solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to edit the tags themselves, I just wanted to add the "#" for visual purposes.

I decided to add this to the CSS to solve the problem:

```
.tags a::before {
    content: '#';
}
```

Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: *I didn't want to edit the tags themselves* FYI, my code do **not**  change the tags. It is a simple filter that alter how the tags are displayed. It changes nothing in db or the tags itself. You need to learn how filters work. If you remove the filter, the tags will be displayed as normal. Anyways, this makes your question off topic as this is a generic js/css question as you are not interested in a WordPress solution

Comment: Answer seems illogical, css can be messy, and u are using a class on div, what if the div has some other a that isnt a hashtag, your question also isnt good UX point of view either. Why add unnecessary complexity to

Answer (score 2):

Using JS is not really the best possible solution as it can be disabled on client side. You can also use PHP like regular expressions and DOM to alter the links, but I really think the most reliable way to achive this is to rebuild the list throught the [`term_link-post_tag` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_links-taxonomy/) which is located inside the [`get_the_term_list()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/) which is used by [`get_the_tag_list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tag_list/) which in turn is used by [`the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_tags/).

The following is untested, but you can try something like this

```
add_filter( 'term_link-post_tag', function ( $links )
{
    // Return if $links are empty
    if ( empty( $links ) )
        return $links;

    // Reset $links to an empty array
    unset ( $links );
    $links = [];

    // Get the current post ID
    $id = get_the_ID();
    // Get all the tags attached to the post
    $taxonomy = 'post_tag';
    $terms = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );

    // Make double sure we have tags
    if ( !$terms )
        return $links; 

    // Loop through the tags and build the links
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

        // Here we add our hastag, so we get #Tag Name with link
        $links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">#' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }

    return $links;
});
```

Comment: This got me curious of other ways, maybe if I got time tomorrow, I will try ;-)

Comment: Looking forward to your answer. ;-)